# Is a non-profile save able to be transferred between xbox 360s?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a game (actually, one I'm creating) that saves **shared** data; i.e. any profile can use it.

Can I transfer this onto a USB/MU and use it on another xbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, game saves can be transfered between Xbox 360 consoles.